# Umbraco 4.6 - macros not rendering

Tags: macros, umbraco, aliases

I posted this on the Umbraco forum but to no avail, and wondered if the community at large might be able to offer some advice.  We are upgrading our site from 4.0.3 to 4.6.  I can't deploy it though as the macros aren't rendering - the error states the following about 30 times:

```
UmbracoPage Aliases must be unique, and element with alias 'data' has already been loaded!
```

And also says:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$ctl28' were found. Trace requires that controls have unique IDs.
```

I tried deleting the contents of my data file but this didn't help.. I also have 22 duplicate 'homepage' templates that Umbraco won't delete (possibly an issue for another post - or it could be related!).

Comment: can you please check for duplicate aliases

Comment: It could be a problem with the xml schema. I think it's changed in umbraco 4.5. You can set your application to use the legacy schema, have you done it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the issue basically:

"Multiple controls with the same ID..." or in potentially no ID

You most likely have two Macros (of same type/alias) on the page and you are not specifying an ID for them.

Example:

```
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="TestMacro" runat="server" />
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="TestMacro" runat="server" />
```

If you want to render the same macro twice on the same page.
Then you must give them a unique ID (see below):

```
    <umbraco:Macro ID="macro1" Alias="TestMacro" runat="server" />
    <umbraco:Macro ID="macro2" Alias="TestMacro" runat="server" />
```